# Angular4 Material sidenav not working

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to test out the sidenav functionality in angular4 material. From whatever information I could gather from google. I made this plunker.
https://plnkr.co/edit/4VfijY?p=preview

```
<md-sidenav-container>
  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true">
    <md-nav-list>
      <a md-list-item>
        Home
      </a>
      <a md-list-item>
        Channels
      </a>
    </md-nav-list>
  </md-sidenav>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

Could someone point out what am I doing wrong ?. I could use another pair of eyes.

Also if someone has successfully made a working sidenav or has a good tutorial could you please share here ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've made a starter based on angular-cli and material but it uses ngrx too : https://github.com/maxime1992/angular-ngrx-starter If you're not familiar with Redux you should either learn more about Redux first or just take a look into what you're interested with the sidenav and do not pay too much attention to the starter itself

Comment: It took some time to understand what you were trying to do but its really magnificent and definitely teaches you how to organise and scale an angular2/4 app.

Answer (score 3):

Structure of your code is wrong. For sidenav to work all your html code should be inside `md-sidenav-container`. `sidenav.open()` method is used to open side nav.

this is working plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/3Oalufvj8ieRzhYPq7RP?p=preview

```
<md-sidenav-container>
    <md-sidenav #sidenav>
        <md-nav-list>
            <a md-list-item>
        Home
      </a>
            <a md-list-item>
        Channels
      </a>
        </md-nav-list>
    </md-sidenav>

    <!--***** html part of page should be inside sidenav here *****-->
    <div style="height: 700px;">
        <md-toolbar color="primary">
            Angular Material 2 App
        </md-toolbar>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <button md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">Open sidenav</button>
            <p>
                <md-slide-toggle>Slide Toggle</md-slide-toggle>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

for more info read this https://material.angular.io/components/component/sidenav

i hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks Amit Kumar I think this is the correct solution.

Comment: I have one more question how can we get the sidenav below the toolbar when mode="side". Any ideas ?

Comment: @codestruggle Put toolbar outside sidenav. Try some position style like absolute or relative. Hope it will help. Also don't forget to accept my answer by marking correct. If you still face issue then send me message on LinkedIn. I will try to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Angular2 material package? use npm command like:

npm i --save @angular/material